# Failed to authenticate with proxy - Android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, proxy, android-emulator, lan

I am getting this error **Failed to authenticate with proxy** when android application run on emulator and I am using LAN internet connection not wifi.
I have already tried this :
1.) Adding Emulator Command Options in eclipse(-avd avdName -dns-server list  -http-proxy http://username:password@proxy_ip:port)

2.) Add Proxy details in SDK Manager
3.) Already Configured Proxy details in emulator setting under Mobile Networks.(Internet is not working in emulator browser.) 
4.) Already Configured users/.android/androidtool.cfg properties.

But still get **Failed to authenticate with proxy** Can anyone help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of efforts this problem resolved.
Please do this steps:
1.) Add -dns-server 8.8.8.8 into Additional Emulator Command Line Options(Run > Run Configuration).(**Note**: I have added this DNS details because I don't need any proxy .)
2.) Add Proxy Details in Emulator Setting >Wireless And Networks > Mobile Networks> APN>.
3.) Make sure that Your IDE and emulator runs with Administrator Credentials.